# How to run more than one test cases using appium?

Tags: selenium, appium

I am trying to automate Mobile application after successful login I want to log out and run other test cases also.How to do login code at that time??every time I need to login into the application and every time I need to write Desired capability code??

Comment: Please tell us more in details and more specific.

Comment: Actually, i am able to log in through automation script but now i am trying to do further test cases but did not understand every time i need to log in into an application? i have already write desired capability code so how to write further code?

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question, You need to have an extra class, where you have a method where you initialize desired capabilities.

For Example ,

```
class A{
void capabilities()
{
capabilities.setCapability ("unicodeKeyboard","true");
....
....
}

getDiver()
{
driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL(appiumServiceUrl), getCapability());
}

}
```

now call in test class file,
   A a=new A();
   this.driver = appInitializer.getDriver();

Hope ,it will help :)